# how to print paragraphs of strings out of columns in R?

Tags: r, string, data-wrangling

### Problem

I have a dataset `df` (see below) with several columns. And I would like to concatenate all columns and print a single paragraph row by row as you can see in `Expected output`. I would like to use `\r\n` as the syntax to create a paragraph in the output.

### Data to import

```
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(ID = c(001, 002, 003, 004),
         resp = c("this is the response of the subject one... \r\n and more and more...",
                  "Host: this is the response of the subject two",
                  "now a response from subejct three",
                  "that is a different one, \r\n and it is from subject 4"),
         comment = c("now a comment from the assessor",
                     NA,
                     "No comments",
                     "I don't agree with this comment"))
```

### Input

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
     ID resp                                              comment                         
  <dbl> <chr>                                             <chr>                           
1     1 this is the response of the subject one           now a comment from the assessor 
2     2 this is the response of the subject two           NA                              
3     3 now a response from subejct three                 No comments                     
4     4 that is a different one, and it is from subject 4 I don't agree with this comment
```

### expected output

```
" 
Participant: 001
Response: this is the response of the subject one... 
          and more and more...
Comment: now a comment from the assessor

Participant: 002
Response: Host: this is the response of the subject two
Comment: NA

Participant: 003
Response: now a response from subejct three
Comment: No comments

Participant: 004
Response: that is a different one, 
          and it is from subject 4
Comment: I don't agree with this comment "
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  What's your intended destination: console, text file, markdown, etc?

Answer (score 2):

```
out_string = ""
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  out_string <- sprintf("%sParticipant: %03d \r\nResponse: %s \r\nComment: %s \r\n\r\n" ,
                        out_string, i, df$resp[i],df$comment[i])
}

cat(out_string)
```

Comment: So the `%03d` handles the front padding needed as ID is single digit?

Answer (score 1):

Fetching cell wise values and using them.

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
{
    for (j in 1:ncol(df))
    {
        a<-as.character(df[i,j])
        b<-as.character(df[i,j])
        c<-as.character(df[i,j])
        if(j==1){
            cat("Participant : ",a)
            cat("\n")
        }else if(j==2){
            cat("Response : ",b)
            cat("\n")
        }else if(j==3){
            cat("Comment : ",c)
            cat("\n")
        }
    }
    cat("\n")
}
```

[image: Output Of Above code]